# Div follow cursor only within specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor, mouseevent

I would like a div `.drag-indicator` to follow the cursor, and disappear once a click occurs. The below code achieves this, however I only want this behaviour to happen when hovering over a specific div `.carousel`. The current code make .drag-indicator follow the mouse regardless of position on the screen, and when any click is made, not just within that div.

I'm sure my code could be streamlined somewhat too, so any advice here would be great. I'd like to make it just a single function.

Thanks.

```js
/* Follow cursor */
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.drag-indicator').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});

/* Hide when clicked */
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  $('.drag-indicator').fadeOut(300)
});
```

```css
.drag-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="drag-indicator">DRAG INDICATOR</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work as you require, attach the event handlers directly to `.carousel` instead of the `document`:

```js
$('.carousel').on({
  mousemove: function(e) {
    $('.drag-indicator').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    })
  },
  mousedown: function(e) {
    $('.drag-indicator').fadeOut(300)
  }
});
```

```css
.drag-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.carousel {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}

.carousel .drag-indicator {
  display: none;
}
.carousel:hover .drag-indicator {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">CELL CONTENT</div>
  <div class="drag-indicator">DRAG INDICATOR</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks Rory! That works well, however would it be possible to make .drag-indicator hide when not hovering over .carousel? At the moment, when the hover ends the 'drag-indicator just remains in the last known position. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure, you can use CSS to do that. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Thanks Rory, I'm having issues with the .fadeOut function, it's no longer working for me but can see in your example in works fine. Any ideas? Also, I'm getting quite a lot of flicker when moving the mouse?

Comment: Without seeing whats happening it's going to be hard to diagnose any problems, sorry.

Comment: The flicking is now resolved, that was a CSS bug when momentarily hovering over .drag-indicator. Here is a tunneling link to the dev site, I can't work out why the mousedown event isn't working any more? http://bc621100.ngrok.io